# CSS opacity animation inside transforming element

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

What I want to do:

I am transforming (translating and rotating) 2 elements side by side that both have content inside. The content has another animation. It fades in or fades out while the parent is transforming.

The problem:

Whenever I add the opacity animation for the content, the second (transforming) element will always render on top of the other in Android devices. But it renders correctly in desktop browsers and in iOS devices. Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdjhT.png) of how it should look (notice how the red block is behind the purple one).

If I remove the content fade animation, it starts rendering correctly on Android devices.

How can I fix it, so that it also works correctly in Android devices?

Note: The content can be text, images, several nested elements, etc. I'm using just a simple text to simplify the problem.

Here is a simplification of the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block-1">
    <div class="content content-1">Bye</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block block-2">
    <div class="content content-2">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>


.block {
  @extend %full;
  @extend %animation;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;

  &.block-1 {
    background-color: purple;
    animation-name: move-out;
  }
  &.block-2 {
    background-color: red;
    animation-name: move-in;
  }
}

.content {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  @extend %animation;

  &.content-1 {
     animation-name: fade;
  }
  &.content-2 {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-direction: reverse;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/Ostos/pen/YZZzmm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several ways of trying to fix this, I found that the best approach would be to make the content be a sibling of the rotating parent, and add both the rotating animation and the fading animation on the content. Android devices apparently can handle elements with both animations, but not a parent with a transform with a child with an opacity animation.